# Die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln wurden geändert

Tags: discussion, news

## Die Neuigkeit

Mit der Bestätigung durch alle zuständigen Stellen sind heute die jüngsten Änderungen an der deutschen Rechtschreibung in Kraft getreten ([Pressemitteilung](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_PM_2017-06-29_Aktualisierung_Regelwerk.pdf)). Diese Änderungen sind:

- Das Versaleszett (ẞ) ist als Alternative zu *SS* zugelassen, man kann nun also z. B. *MAẞSTAB* statt *MASSSTAB* schreiben.
- Die Groß- und Kleinschreibung von festen Verbindungen aus Adjektiven und Substantiven wie *die mittlere Reife* wurde neu geregelt.
- Einige eingedeutschte Schreibungen von Fremdwörtern wurden abgeschafft.
- Weitere kleine Änderungen am Wörterverzeichnis.

Die kompletten aktuellen Regeln finden sich [hier](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2017.pdf).

## Was bedeutet das für uns?

#### Aktualisierung alter Antworten

Einige alte Antworten verlieren ihre Gültigkeit oder müssen aktualisiert werden. Ich ermutige alle Nutzer, ungültige Antworten aufzuspüren und:

- zu editieren, wenn eine Antwort größtenteils gültig bleibt;
- eine neue Antwort zu verfassen, falls die nötige Überarbeitung zu schwerwiegend wäre. Kennzeichnet in diesem Fall die ungültige Antwort, z. B. mit:

  > *Diese Antwort ist durch die Änderung der deutschen Rechtschreibregeln am 29.06.2017 betroffen und daher nicht mehr auf dem aktuellsten Stand.*

#### Neue Fragen

Zögert nicht, Fragen zu den Regeländerungen zu stellen. Dies ist eine gute Möglichkeit für uns, im Internet zu glänzen. Es könnte auch sein, dass neue Nutzer Fragen zu den Änderungen stellen.

#### Bounties

Als zusätzlichen Ansporn, sich mit den Regeländerungen auseinanderzusetzen (sei es, um Fragen zu stellen oder zu beantworten), plane ich, in den nächsten Wochen mindestens 500 Erfahrungspunkte an Bounties auf neue Fragen oder auf neue Antworten auf alte Fragen auszuschreiben, die jeweils in Bezug zu den Änderungen stehen.

Comment: Geht es nur mir auf meinem iMac und meinem Macbook so, oder ist das ein allgemeines Problem?: Das große scharfe S erscheint (zumindest auf den Seiten von german.SE) auf meinem Bildschirm immer fett und sticht daher aus normal gesetzten Worten heraus. Veranschaulichung: 1. Nichts fett markiert: MAẞSTAB. 2. Alles fett: **MAẞSTAB**. 3. Nur das ẞ fett: MA**ẞ**STAB. 4. Alles außer ẞ fett: **MA**ẞ**STAB**. Bei mir sehen 1 und 3 gleich aus, ebenso 2 und 4 .

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das zumindest mir nicht so und es liegt wahrscheinlich an Deinen installierten Schriften. (Siehe auch [diese Frage](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/problem-mit-dem-gro%c3%9fen-%c3%9f-durch-die-app-stack-exchange-auf-meinem-handy).)

Comment: @Hubert The trouble is that this site (like many others, including Wikipedia and Google) has Arial set as the first font choice, Helvetica as the second, and a generic sans-serif font as the third. Since the versions of Arial and Helvetica that come bundled with OS X and macOS do not include capital eszett glyph, the generic sans-serif font gets used instead, and it’s up to the rendering engine to decide what that is. In Webkit browsers on macOS/OS X, it’s Helvetica Neue DeskInterface, which is the system font that was used in Yosemite; in Firefox, it’s Times New Roman (which is odd, →

Comment: → since that’s not a sans serif font at all). The thing that makes it look so weird is that, bizarrely, the capital eszett glyph is not present in any of the Helvetica Neue DeskInterface variants either, _except Helvetica Neue DeskInterface Heavy_. Why they included it in that weight, but none of the others, is anyone’s guess, but they did, and that’s what shows up.

Comment: I might add that the situation is different in iOS. The version of whatever font is being used to render the glyph there does have both a regular and a bold version of it, so you can see the difference. Interestingly, if you use the iOS app (which uses the new system font San Francisco), the situation is reversed: there is a regular capital eszett, but no bold!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Thank you very much for this information. Do you know, if this is already is reported as a bug to Apple? Or do you know how to report it?

Comment: @Hubert I don’t think it’s possible to search Apple’s Bug Reporter (except in your own submitted bugs), so I don’t know if it’s been reported already. I’ll file a bug now.

Comment: Ich denke bezüglich des großen ß werden wir vielleicht die ein oder andere Frage dazu bekommen (bzw. haben wohl schon eine), aber es besteht kaum Notwendigkeit es im regulären Gebrauch auf SE zu verwenden - im Gegenteil. Wir haben die Möglichkeit der Hervorhebung mittels fetten und schreiben hier auch keine AGB, die möglichst niemand lesen soll.

Answer (score 2):

Nichts **muss** aktualisiert werden. Wenn ich auf SO eine Frage zu C++ aus dem Jahr 2010 lese, weiß ich auch, dass die Antworten nicht unbedingt C++11 berücksichtigen. Wenn jemand ein klar gekennzeichnetes Addendum zu einer einigen Antwort verfasst, ist das ein netter Service. Antworten aus der Zukunft verwirren hingegen.

Comment: Dass Antworten aktualisiert werden dürfen und sollen, gehört zu den Grundsätzen von Stack Exchange. Siehe z. B. [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/editing) oder auch den Bounty-Grund “Current answers are outdated”.

Comment: *Adding updates* bedeutet aber nicht, die Antwort zu ersetzen. Ich habe ja geschrieben, dass ein Addendum eine gute Sache ist.

Comment: "Antworten aus der Zukunft" finde ich immer gut, desto früher desto besser. Hoffentlich verfangen wir uns nicht in Zeitschleifen hier, das wäre wirklich verwirrend. *SCNR*

Comment: @Thomas. Klar doch, Marty.

Comment: Du weißt das, bezüglich C++ weiß ich es, bezüglich der dt. Sprache wissen wir beide es, aber Anfänger, die jetzt erst Deutsch lernen wissen und ahnen es wahrscheinlich nicht.