# Problem mit dem großen ß durch die App "Stack Exchange" auf meinem Handy

Tags: support, user-interface

Seit 24 Stunden habe ich auf meinem Laptop angefangen das große ß, ẞ, zu schreiben, allerdings habe ich auf meinen Handy ein Problem, nämlich kann ich dieses große ß nicht richtig sehen.

Ein Beispiel dafür:

[image: The app doesn’t display the 'ß' correctly, the site does.]

Ich kann außerdem nicht verstehen, ob das Problem bei mir oder bei der App "Stack Exchange" liegt, weil die Sprache der Tastatur und meines Handys, Samsung S5 mini, die ich damals ausgewählt habe, Deutsch war.

Answer (score 6):

Das liegt ganz einfach daran, dass die Schriftart, die die App einsetzt, kein großes ß unterstützt. Ich würde das am besten auf https://meta.stackexchange.com/ posten (oder kann das jemand verschieben?).

Comment: ... aus genau diesem Grund würde ich im Internet immer das "normale" (kleine) "scharfe S" nehmen, wenn ich eigentlich ein "großes" schreiben müsste. Die beiden Buchstaben sehen fast gleich aus.

Comment: Verschieben ist nicht sinnvoll, da dies auf Deutsch geschrieben ist. Außerdem ist fraglich, ob SE überhaupt etwas dafür kann (siehe Carstens Antwort).

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Das funktioniert aber nicht, wenn man über das Zeichen selbst redet oder Versalsatz um des Beispiels willen nutzt. Und da wir hier sonst keinen Versalsatz brauchen, ist das so ziemlich der einzige Grund, das große Ezsett hier explizit zu nutzen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Da hast du recht. Ich hätte allerdings beim betroffenen Beitrag das große "ß" in den Klammern weggelassen - schon alleine deswegen, weil es auch auf meinem Rechner nicht funktioniert.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: *Ich hätte allerdings beim betroffenen Beitrag das große "ß" in den Klammern weggelassen* – und damit riskiert, dass jemand, der das Zeichen selbst zum Suchen relevanter Fragen nutzt, sie nicht findet. Da es nur in Klammern ist, richtet es ja keinen Schaden an.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft StackExchange should be able to do something about it if they deemed it really important. Apps can and frequently do embed fonts, and it should be possible to embed a font which contains the glyph. The app likely uses the default system font as it is now, and that’s the font that doesn’t have the glyph; but they could change that.

Answer (score 5):

Das Problem ist wahrscheinlich schlicht dein Telefon, ich habe das Problem nämlich mit der Android-App nicht. Die meisten Android-Geräte bekommen kaum Updates, so dass es wahrscheinlich schwer wird, das zu ändern. Ob es doch möglich ist, ist eher eine Android-Frage.